# Style Radio Button with no label using css

Tags: html

How i can style my radio button with no label like shown below

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Default radio buttons are usually not styleable. You can create your own with CSS, JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 1):

Use css for radio button like this

```css
body {
    padding: 25px;
}
.radio {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.radio:before {
  background: #fff;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;

  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;

  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0 #ccc;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
} 
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2022";
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;
}
```

```html
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio">
<label for="radio1" class="radio"></label>
```